# Permission Denied When Building in Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows, lua, sublimetext3

I am attempting to utilize Lua on Windows 10 with Sublime Text 3.  When I attempt to build and run a script I receive the following error:

> lua: cannot open C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1: Permission denied

I have added full permissions to the folder.

I am only attempting to run a simple print statement:
`print("hello")`

The expected result is `hello` output in the results window.

Comment: Did you make a custom build system or are you using the default?

Comment: Nothing custom.  All out of the box.  Windows is a relatively new, within the last 30 days.  The Sublime Text 3 install is the base install; it is registered.  The Lua for Windows install is also the base install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build system that ships with Sublime for executing Lua programs looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["lua", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(?:lua:)?[\t ](...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.lua"
}
```

The important aspect here is that the command to be executed is `lua` with a first argument that is the name of the current file. From the error message you're seeing, Lua looks like it's trying to execute a directory instead of the name of a program. Or if you will, if this was a directory permission problem I would expect it to tell you the name of the file that it can't access, not the folder than the file is stored in.

It's also suspicious that the name of the folder is the install location for `lua` itself, and that the error message seems to indicate that it's `lua` itself generating the error.

Based on all of this, my guess would be that you didn't save your Lua script before you executed the command. That would cause `$file` to expand out to an empty string, making the first argument empty. Since the build is using `cmd`, internally windows is being told specifically to run a program named `lua` with an empty string as it's first argument.

It looks like the interpreter first tries to put the current working directory onto the filename and then execute it, and since the file name is empty, it ends up trying to execute a directory, which is where the permission problem comes from.

Once you save the file the first time and it has a name, Sublime will automatically re-save it every time you run the build as long as `Tools > Save all on build` is checked; that option won't prompt you to save brand new files that don't have names yet, though.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for your help!!